# Exercise 7 and 8 are on page 5. (pronunciation)

Tags: reading-aloud

> **Exercise 7 and 8 are on page 5.**

How do you pronounce that sentence?

*Exercise seven and eight are on page five.*

or

*The seventh and eighth exercise are on the fifth page.*

Or are both versions possible?

Comment: The first, if you are reading the text aloud. It should really be 'Exercises 7 and 8', because there are two of them. Also, what you are asking about is not really pronunciation.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It really is about pronunciation. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is pronounced exactly as written.

My guess is this question arises from dates like "March 1" being pronounced "March first" when read aloud, rather than "<del>March one</del>".

Dates are special in this way. In English, dates and numbers after people's names (William Henry Gates III) or titles (Pope Gregory XIII) are the only cardinal numbers in written form which are pronounced like ordinals when read aloud.

Comment: Not quite true; it's dates and name suffixes (as for kings and popes). *Henry VIII* is pronounced *Henry the eighth* when read aloud, and similarly *John Doe III* is pronounced *John Doe the third*.

Comment: @PeterShor You're right. And as I wrote it I thought there was a chance I was going to be corrected. Happy for it.